# Sql bulk delete text content between two markers

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to bulk delete textual content between two known markers?

I need to do this to avoid manually editing 600 posts.

The content to be deleted is in this form:

```
[:en] content to remove [:]
```

In addition to the content to be removed I need to also eliminate the markers [:en] and [:] in the wordpress tables wp_post and wp_content.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is an update statement to remove the text inside a column and not a delete statement (removes rows). You can get there with this ugly work-around:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourColumn = CONCAT(
  SUBSTR(yourColumn, 1, INSTR(yourColumn, '[:en]') - 1),
  SUBSTR(yourColumn, INSTR(SUBSTR(yourColumn, INSTR(yourColumn, '[:en]')), '[:]')
                   + INSTR(yourColumn, '[:en]') + 3)
)
WHERE yourColumn LIKE '%[:en]%[:]%'
```

The reasoning behind it: find the indexes of [:en] and the first [:] after the [:en] (by only taking the substring after [:en], but then the length of what was cut away has to be added +3 for the length of [:]) and then take the substring before and after and concat.

Rewritten as select statement to prove it works: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73f63/5/0)